# Creating a Dynamic Type

Tags: c#

When creating a dynamic type with `System.Reflection.Emit`.

```
private AssemblyName _assemblyName;
private AssemblyBuilder _asssemblyBuilder;
private ModuleBuilder _moduleBuilder;
private TypeBuilder _typeBuilder;

// Create the new assembly
_assemblyName = new AssemblyName("ModuleName");
_asssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(_assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

I am having trouble building the dynamic constructor. I am able to create the `ILGenerator` but can not find anymore information on what parameters I should pass when calling `Emit`.

```
// Create the default constructor.
ConstructorInfo baseConstructorInfo = typeof(object).GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder = 
      _typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
                 MethodAttributes.Public,
                 CallingConventions.Standard,
                 Type.EmptyTypes);

// Create the base call operations.
ILGenerator ilGenerator = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
```

What do I place in the `Emit` call? What needs to be added, and at what point is the dynamic constructor complete?

```
ilGenerator.Emit(?);
ilGenerator.Emit(?);
ilGenerator.Emit(?);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: `Emit` receives instances of the `OpCodes` enum. Exactly which ones depends entirely on what you want the constructor to do. Have you decided what's its body would look like in (say) C#?